# How to enable auto scaling for SQL app in Azure Portal

Tags: sql, azure, triggers, autoscaling

I am looking to allow auto-scaling from my SQL DB app in Azure portal so that allow it to increase to 200 DTUs on a particular day and then automatically scale back down to 20. I seem to be getting confused as to how to go about it as I'm aware I will need to use Azure cli also. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna scale SQL in Azure on some schedule I would recommend you to prepare Automation service with PowerShell script and schedules connected to that Runbook. Also you would need to configure Run as options.

I personally use this script to scale DB up and down on daily base.

```
## Authentication
Write-Output ""
Write-Output "------------------------ Authentication ------------------------"
Write-Output "Logging into Azure ..."

$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

##DB Part

$vCores = 18
$currentTier = "GP_Gen5"
$size = 200
$resourceGroup = ""
$serverName = ""
$databaseName = ""
$db_size = "GP_Gen5_4"

Write-Output "Changing DB type to GP_Gen5_4"

Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase `
               -ServerName $serverName `
               -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
               -DatabaseName $databaseName `
               -RequestedServiceObjectiveName $db_size
#               -RequestedServiceObjectiveName "$currentTier" + "_" + "$vCores"

Write-Output "Writing current DB parameters"

Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase `
               -ServerName $serverName `
               -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
               -DatabaseName $databaseName
```